# Subscribing to an event of a Binding class in custom MarkupExtension

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm writing a MarkupExtension that is able to accept PropertyPath. I'd like to be able to subscribe to the "Change" events of the given property PropertyPath (either DependencyProperty or one that is updated via INotifyPropertyChanged) **without** ever actually calling to the source property.

My code currently looks like so:

```
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var binding = new Binding();
        binding.Path = Path;
        ...

        return false;
    }
```

But I am not sure how to continue to get notification changes from the binding object. If I connect the binding to any DependencyProperty, it will automatically call the source property getter, which is what I am trying to avoid.

It seems that I could somehow use Binding.SourceUpdatedEvent, however, since it is an attached routed event, I am not sure how to subscribe to it from the MarkupExtension.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212597/wpf-how-should-i-evaluate-a-property-path)

The idea is to make a class with one DP, feed it and let WPF handle the propertypath, then retrieve the value that comes out.

If that's not satisfying, you're looking at reflection (a lot of it).

Comment: Thanks for the input. I saw this question, but the problem is that I am trying to get notified of Source changes, without actually calling the getter of the source. The problem with this solution is that the DP that is bound to the PropertyPath will actually retrieve the value, while I just want to know that the value changed.

Answer (score 0):

If Binding and DependancyProperty is a solution for you and you are concerned about not calling the getter, you can specify the binding mode as `OneWayToSource.`

```
{Binding Mode=OneWayToSource}
```

Or in code

```
binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWayToSource;
```

Comment: I don't think he meant using XAML

Comment: He can set the binding in code easily. The key is using `Mode = OneWayToSource`

Comment: Even though, your solution doesn't resolve PropertyPath in order to subscribe to changes.

Comment: It is an interesting solution, however, how do I get the notification when the source changed? It seems that using OneWayToSource disabled any notifications and events on source change.

Comment: I thought you don't want the getter invoked? Now you do?

Comment: I don't want the getter of the source invoked, but I do want to be notified when it changes. If I set `OneWayToSource` then I also don't get any notification when the source changes.