# A delayed binding from source

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

Consider the following ViewModel property:

```
private string _slowProperty;
public string SlowProperty
{
    get { return _slowProperty; }
    set
    {
        _slowProperty = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("SlowProperty");
    }
}
```

Which is bound to a textbox, like so:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SlowProperty}" />
```

Now, the problem here is that every time the value of SlowProperty changes, and it does so quite often, the textbox would go and try to get its value, which is, quite slow. I could alleviate the situation using async binding, however, that would still be wasting CPU cycles.

Instead, what I'd like to have is something like:

```
<TextBlock Text="{z:DelayedSourceBinding SlowProperty}" />
```

Which would try to get the binding after a certain delay. So for example if the `SlowProperty`changed 5 times in a row, within a short while, then only the last text would be visible in the textbox.

I've found the [following project](http://www.paulstovell.com/wpf-delaybinding) that performs something like that, so it my example I could use it like so:

```
<TextBox Text="{z:DelayBinding Path=SearchText}" />
```

The problem with it, is that it only updates the binding **target** after a delay. The source path, however, is evaluated and its getter is executed upon every change of the source. Which, in the case of `SlowProperty` would still waste CPU cycles.

I've tried to make my own delayed binding class, but [got stuck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634909/subscribing-to-an-event-of-a-binding-class-in-custom-markupextension). Is there any other binder that can do anything like that?

For completeness sake, here are 2 other projects that perform similar tasks, yet, none address the problem I am experiencing:

[DeferredBinding](http://julmar.com/blog/mark/?p=30) - A similar solution to DelayBinding. However, it is a bit more complex to use.

[DelayedBindingTextBox](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/DelayedBindingTextBox.aspx) - Implements delayed binding using a custom textbox control.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not solve this problem in the view model? If your property changes rapidly, but is slow to get, you could have a second 'delayed' property exposed by your view model. You could use a timer to update this 'delayed' property periodically.

Or, a cleaner implementation could use the [Throttle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff707633%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) function provided by the reactive extensions framework.

Comment: Colin, excellent. All CS problems can be solved by adding another layer of indirection! :)

Comment: You are probably right, this is, indeed, a problem that should be solved on the VM level. Though, I still would like to know if it is possible to do a custom binding, like the one I described.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar requirement a while back where I needed to be able to delay both source and target so I created two markup extensions called `DelayBinding` and `DelayMultiBinding`. To delay an update to the source you specify `UpdateSourceDelay`

```
<TextBox Text="{db:DelayBinding SlowProperty,
                                UpdateSourceDelay='00:00:01'}" />
```

The source code and sample usage for `DelayBinding` and `DelayMultiBinding` can be [downloaded here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/39657172/Blog/DelayBindingDemo.zip).
If you're interested in the implementation details, you can check out my blog post about it here:
[DelayBinding and DelayMultiBinding with Source and Target delay](http://meleak.wordpress.com/2012/05/02/delaybinding-and-delaymultibinding-with-source-and-target-delay/)

Comment: Source no longer available it seems. Do you have it on Github perhaps? :-) It is now possible to introduce a delay from target to source using the Delay binding property but not the other way around AFAIK, so your library still seems useful! Especially when binding to properties that generate UIElements and hence IsAsync is not applicable (must be done on UI thread).

Answer (score 2):

Of note, as of .Net 4.5, a [delay property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.delay(v=vs.110).aspx) has been added to the framework, which lets you set the amount of binding delay by milliseconds.  In the Microsoft example, the `twoway` mode is emphasized but the binding delay works in any binding mode.

For example, I used this in a datagrid where the selected item / value had to be changed both from a textbox within a custom usercontrol and obviously from within the datagrid. Because of reasons I won't mention here, the textbox had to bind to a property different from the view model, but both properties had to have the same value at the end of the day, and any change in one of them had to be reflected on the other. When the selected value changed in datagrid, the text box had to be updated too, and I checked for actual value changes in the setter of the SelectedValue binded property, to prevent infinite looping. When the change was too fast, there was an error saving the data back to source when the text changed inside the textbox which was changed by the SelectedValue setter. A two frame delay fixed the problem without any complex solutions and without the UI feeling too laggy:

```
SelectedValue="{Binding SampleNumberSelect, Mode=OneWayToSource, Delay=33}"
```

This is very convenient and saves you the hassle of implementing any such changes in the view model, which would unnecessarily clutter the code, including having to dispose any timers on window closing. Of course it doesn't even have to be used in a relatively complex scenario like mine, but it could be helpful to prevent CPU / resource heavy code from running unnecessarily with each small change in the UI.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me what you really want is delay the point when RaisePropertyChanged() is called.
So I tried it out, and here is a solution:

The XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding DelayedText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DelayedText}" />
</StackPanel>
```

The C#:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        private String m_DelayedText;
        public String DelayedText 
        {
            get
            {
                return m_DelayedText;
            }
            set
            {
                if (m_DelayedText != value)
                {
                    String delayedText;
                    m_DelayedText = delayedText = value;
                    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                        {
                            Thread.Sleep(2000);
                            if (delayedText == m_DelayedText)
                            {
                                RaisePropertyChanged("DelayedText");
                            }
                        });
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void RaisePropertyChanged(String _Prop)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(_Prop));
            }
        }
    }
```

You can check that it works by setting a breakpoint at `RaisePropertyChanged("DelayedText")`

I understand that it can look like quite a lot of code for "just" a property. 
But you can use code snippets, or inject the boilerplate code at runtime using Resharper and the like.
And anyway, you probably won't need it so often.

Also, if you were to use another approach (for example, by tweaking a TextBox), you will have to handle every place where you bind to the property.
By doing it this way, in the property's setter, you ensure everyone who accesses this property is restricted on the updates recieved.

HTH,

Bab.

Comment: Interesting solution, thanks! It is indeed a bit heavy on the resulting code, but it was an interesting read.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Delay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingbase.delay?view=netframework-4.7.2) property as a part of the binding, but it only works from target to the source.
Anyway, in this working example I will show you **how you can use the Delay property in the opposite direction**:

In the view's code behind I forward updates coming from the original source to the control's `Tag` (see `Foo_DataContextChanged`). 
The tag binding specifies the delay and is bound to the the `DelayedViewProperty` property on the view.
The actual content of the control content is bound to the `DelayedViewProperty`.

```
<Window x:Class="DelayedControl.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<StackPanel>
    <Button Click="Button_Click">Set time</Button>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ViewModelProperty}" IsReadOnly="True" ToolTip="Not delayed"></TextBox>

    <!-- The DelayedViewProperty is on the code behind (Window in this case), set DataContext as needed -->
    <TextBox x:Name="foo" DataContextChanged="Foo_DataContextChanged" IsReadOnly="True" ToolTip="Delayed"
             Tag="{Binding DelayedViewProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window},
                    Delay=500, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
             Text="{Binding DelayedViewProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, 
                    Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace DelayedControl
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this; // treat this as a view model for simplification..
        }

        public string DelayedViewProperty
        {
            get => delayedViewProperty;
            set
            {
                delayedViewProperty = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(DelayedViewProperty)));
            }
        }
        private string delayedViewProperty;


        private void Foo_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.NewValue is INotifyPropertyChanged vm)
            {
                // Forward updates of the view model property to the foo.Tag
                vm.PropertyChanged += (s, args) =>
                {
                    var propertyName = nameof(ViewModelProperty);
                    if (args.PropertyName == propertyName && s?.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName)?.GetValue(s) is var tag)
                    {
                        foo.Tag = tag;  // Dispatcher might be needed if the change is triggered from a different thread..
                    }
                };
            }
        }

        public string ViewModelProperty
        {
            get => viewModelProperty;
            set
            {
                viewModelProperty = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ViewModelProperty)));
            }
        }
        private string viewModelProperty;

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ViewModelProperty = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff");
        }
    }
}
```